# MySQL INSERT error but why?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, insert

Error in SQL query:

```
CREATE trigger new_admin_trig AFTER INSERT ON admins
FOR each
ROW 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO forgot_password_admins( ID_Admin, Admin_Email, Admin_Password ) 
VALUES (

new.ID_Admin, new.Email_ADM, new.Password_ADM
);
```

end;

MySQL said:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 4

Comment: is it full trigger defination ?

Comment: A `BEGIN`, but no `END`

Comment: sorry there was an end but it didnt show on the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common reason for such an error in MySQL is a lack of `delimiter`:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE trigger new_admin_trig AFTER INSERT ON admins
FOR each ROW 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO forgot_password_admins( ID_Admin, Admin_Email, Admin_Password ) 
       VALUES (new.ID_Admin, new.Email_ADM, new.Password_ADM);
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: now says this: Error
SQL query:

DELIMITER;


MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1

Comment: okay i got it working, its because im using phpmyadmin it has built in delimiter function, but your answer was correct